# Javascript code after file Download

Tags: javascript, jquery, download

I want to start some Javascript code after some file download from another domain.

```
        jQuery.support.cors = true;
        var formVars = $("form[name='myForm']").serialize();
        var ajaxUrl = "http://some/path/openFilename.xlsx";


        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxUrl, type: 'GET', cache: false, data: formVars, timeout: 300000,
            success: function (data) {

                //Do some stuff here

            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert("Error" + thrownError);
            },
            complete: function (data) {
                closeWaitScreen();
            }
        });
```

Often read solution is

```
       window.location = ajaxUrl;
```

but this does not work for me, because it starts a new request without submitting the data from the form. (Same with `window.open`)

Here is my code that works without option to handle `closeWaitScreen()` after:

```
      $("form[name='jasperlogin']").submit();
```

Of course also starts a new request when its used in the `$.ajax`

Any ideas how to handle it?

Comment: You could probably submit a form to an iframe, or read the data from the AJAX request and create a download from that.

Comment: Submitting the form to an iframe doesn't work for me because             $("form[name='jasperlogin']").submit();
alert("Something after"); does execute after progress is started, not after end of the progress.

Comment: Did you try using an `onload` event on the `iframe`?

Comment: I think handling the "data" that is available in the success function will be best solution, but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: my onload event fires only on first call of site. I have tryed the following: in iframe onload="javascript: alert('test') | in form target="myIFrame" | in js $("form[name='myForm']").submit();
Something wrong about this?

Comment: You would want to add the event listener just before submitting the data.

Comment: Ok, now the event fires, but also on the start of the progress. Have also tryed onloadeddata event, same here.